# displaying an image in a div after selecting using jquery

Tags: jquery

How to display an image in a div using jQuery? I have this piece of code but it is not working.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#up").click(function () {
        var imgUrl = $("img_input").val();
        $("#imageDiv").prop("src", imgUrl).show();
    });
});
```

where `up` is the `id` given to:

```
<input id="img_input" type="file">
<button id="up">
```

Comment: Show you HTML too. `$("img_input")` looks wrong for a start.

Comment: You are adding `imgUrl` to the attributes of the `#imageDiv`. Should this be **OR** should it be the value of the image tag inside of the `imagDiv`?

Comment: @ROYFinley here is my html

Answer (score 2):

change:

```
$("img_input").val();
```

to

```
$("#img_input").val();
```

If `imageDiv` is id of `div` and image exists inside it, then do:

```
$("#imageDiv").find("img").prop("src", imgUrl).show();
```